# Creating a database relationship that allows for multiple assignments of the same id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm really new to RoR so I apologize if I'm not thinking about this right.  I have a Report where I need to be able to assign multiple users to that report.  A user can be assigned to more than one report and a report can have multiple users.  How do I create the database relationship where this would be allowed.  I understand how to assign one user to one report but not many users to a single report.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a joining class to make this happen:

```
class Report

  has_many :assignments 
  has_many :users :through => :assignments

end

class User

  has_many :assignments
  has_many :reports, :through => :assignments

end

class Assignment

  belongs_to :report
  belongs_to :user

end
```

The class `Assignment` has two fields: `report_id` and `user_id` to create the relationship.

Read the Ruby on Rails Guide to Active Record Associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Ok, starting to make sense, but so I understand it more clearly why would I not use has_and_belongs_to_many as a Report has many Users and Users can belong to many Reports?  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: You could use that, but using the above you get the same functionality plus being able to add fields to the Assignment (like dates, notes, etc) if you want. habtm hides the joining table.  The overall functionality is similar.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you familiarize yourself with the Ruby on Rails guides. They will prove to be an invaluable asset!! For this task the site would be [RailsGuides Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

As far as the code goes you want to create three database tables: reports, reports_users, and users, with reports_users being a join table.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string      :name,        :null => false      
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateReports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reports do |t|
      t.string      :name,        :null => false      
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class ReportsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reports_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.references    :user,            :null => false                            
      t.references    :report,          :null => false                            
    end
  end
end
```

Once you run this migration you need to set up the active record associations in your models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :reports
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user
end
```

This will set up the database and the many-to-many models connections. This will get you started. Now you have to go create some views

Comment: As a side note the Rails Guides site is http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ and another site you should familiarize yourself with is the rails api page at http://api.rubyonrails.org/